# ruby and avro binary data posting to binary json http rest endpoint

Tags: ruby, binary, avro

So I have an endpoint that accepts binary json content-type of `vnd.kafka.binary.v1+json`

I've created the avro object, but how do I format the data to properly call the endpoint?

```
  envelope = Hash.new
  # add some stuff to envelope hash
  .....
  envDatumWriter = Avro::IO::DatumWriter.new(envSchema)
  envBuffer = StringIO.new
  envEncoder = Avro::IO::BinaryEncoder.new(envBuffer)
  envDatumWriter.write(envelope,envEncoder)
```

Should I just do this: `envBuffer.string.to_json_raw_object` and post that to the endpoint?

Comment: Variables and method names in Ruby should be all lower case, as in `env_buffer` and so on. Capital letters are reserved for `CaseName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` type situations and have significant meaning to Ruby itself.

Comment: @tadman are you suggesting that if I rename the variables, that it will magically fix my issue?

Comment: I'm not saying that will fix anything. I'm just pointing out that you can get into trouble if you don't realize that capital letters have significant meaning to Ruby, so take care in naming things.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the correct path. To send it to the endpoint just meant I had to do some extra things specific to the design on the endpoint. Base64 encoding for example as well as json.

```
  envelope = Hash.new
  # add some stuff to envelope hash
  .....
  env_datum_writer = Avro::IO::DatumWriter.new(env_schema)
  env_buffer = StringIO.new("".force_encoding("BINARY"))
  env_encoder = Avro::IO::BinaryEncoder.new(env_buffer)
  env_datum_writer.write(envelope,env_encoder)
  a = Base64.encode64(env_buffer.string.each_byte.to_a.join)
  p_records = Hash.new
  p_records["value"] = a
  p_records_array = [p_records]
```